# One XHR Request at a time after completion of current request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a program that checks if the user id exists by sending the user id by post method to the processId.php using XHR Request. I first tried XHR Requests in the for loop in the array of ids but it killed the browser as it consist of thousands of elements because thousands of XHR requests are made at a time. I then found an a post on StackOverflow which said that I should not be using the XHR Request in the for loop instead I should call the function within the funtion so I wrote the following code. The program seems to work but kills the browser because still thousands of request are made.

I am trying to figure out for a week how to make a single XHR Request at a time after completing the current/in-process XHR Request. Any help? Any solution that I can create a on complete function for this.

PS: I don't want to use jQuery.

```
<?php
$php_array_id = [element-1,element-2.........,element-n];
$js_array_id = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var userIds = ". $js_array_id . ";\n";
$url = "http://example.com/idProcess.php";
?>

<script>

function processNext(i) {
        if (i < userIds.length) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "<?php echo $url ?>";
        var params = "id=" + userIds[i];
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if(this.responseText){
                        document.getElementById("reports").innerHTML += "<div>ID = " + this.responseText + " Exists</div>";
                }
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
        i++;
        processNext(i);

        }
    }

processNext(0);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
var userIds = <?php echo($js_array_id) ?>;

function processNext(i) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "<?php echo($url) ?>";
        var params = "id=" + userIds[i];
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText){
                            document.getElementById("reports").innerHTML += "<div>ID = " + this.responseText + " Exists</div>";
                            i++;
                            if(i<userIds.length){processNext(i);}
                    }
                }
            }
            http.send(params);
    }

processNext(0);
```

Comment: can u please explain the major changes? I think that function should be called within the statechange function? right?

Comment: Yes, so another request will be sent as soon as the previous one is over.

Comment: yeah.. Now it is sending requests when the one is over. thanks.

Comment: it is not sending parameters now.. but the requests are processed one by one

Comment: responses are empty.

Comment: still parameters are not getting processed.

Comment: try add string http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: i think this line is not getting processed. http.send(params);

Comment: great.. setRequestHeader attribute solved the problem. dont know how can you explain?

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded is required if you send data with POST request. Unfortunately, I forgot about it when I wrote a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of [asynchronous callback](http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/)

Say, how comes you want to check thousands of user ids via an xhr ?

Comment: I think that doesn't matters.

Comment: The above answers seems good but it isn't returning any response.